# Best practice to run nextflow pipeline on a single Node of a Cluster using slurm

Tags: slurm, nextflow

I have a nextflow pipeline that i execute on a slurm based cluster. This works very straightforward using the executor:

```
executor {
$slurm {
           ....
}
```

but the issue is, that i have a lot of very small processes that only run for seconds -> therefore i have lot of scheduling overhead (waiting for nodes to be ready to be used...)

is there a clever way to use a single node and run the whole pipeline on it?

My (working) solution is to misuse the local executor and to use a slurm-script to run nextflow... which is not a really satisfying way of doing this.

Best,

t.

Comment: You might be able to configure a single node using the [clusterOptions](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#clusteroptions) directive. I'm not familiar with SLURM so can't say one way or the other. But I think this is an XY problem. The better solution is to refactor away the small tasks somehow.

Comment: thank you - i'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you are tackling this issue is a misuse of slurm. One solution would be refactoring as Steve mentioned, but the reservation of one entire node does sound valid to me:

Best practice is to wrap your nextflow command in a minimalistic shell script and use `sbatch`.

How you configure your batch job strongly depends on the cluster policy and setup. On some clusters you might have specific filesystems on worker nodes for intermediate data, you should make use of them to avoid high I/O between the shared FS where your code/data is located and the worker node. Some clusters have strict quotas which also might kill your job if you write (very large) intermediate data on the shared FS.

Example `script.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16 #should be number of cores you will be using
#SBATCH --job-name=myworkflow

# if you run nextflow from some environmental module or conda env, load it here.
# e.g. module load nextflow 
# or source /path/to/conda/bin/activate /path/to/your/env

# you might have something like $TMPDIR or $SCRATCH on your worker node - if so use it as work-dir
# if it points to /tmp you might want to create a uniquely named subdirectory
# TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)

nextflow run <your command here> -w $TMPDIR/work
rm -rf $TMPDIR/work
```

Submit your job by running `sbatch script.sh`

This way the job will not be run in interactive mode, so you will find some `slurm-<job-id>.out` file in your working directory once the job started. To cancel the job you will have to use `scancel <job-id>`.

SLURM can be configured, to give your jobs lower priority when you submit more jobs than other users or limit your number of simultaneous jobs. This will slow down your workflow in addition to the overhead you mentioned. (Hits especially hard when most nodes are allocated).

---

An other alternative would be to mix executors and specify the executor differently for your short jobs by label e.g.:

```
process {
   executor = "slurm"
   withLabel:small { executor = "local" }
}

executor {
    $local {
        cpus   = 4 // limit local parallel jobs to 4
    }
}
```

I've never tried this, but in theory it should work.

However, then parts of your computation will run on your login-node. You could also limit the number of parallel jobs run "local" to not affect others working interactively. I don't know if this would be allowed on your cluster.

Also, if your slurm jobs are stuck in the queue, your interactive job will have to wait, so maybe use `screen` to detach & re-attach your pipeline execution shell.